# Docker compose: command: bash -c 'apt-get...'. apt-get: not found

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    user: root
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
    command: bash -c "apt-get update && \
                      apt-get install -y curl gnupg apt-transport-https && \
                      curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
                      echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/powershell.list && \
                      apt-get update && \
                      apt-get install -y powershell && \
                      apt-get clean && \
                      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
                      su jenkins -c 'java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war'"
```

From CLI of running Jenkins container I was able to run each command separately but when I run commands by docker compose file I receive the error that apt-get not found.

OS: Windows
Container: Linux

Possibly yml file is not correct but curious why from CLI I was able to run apt-get but from docker compose not?

Thanks in advance!

I create separate image and it help:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

# Install PowerShell
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https && \
    wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y powershell

USER jenkins
```

But it's not a point. The idea is to understand why approach with docker compose do not workout?

Also proposal to run PowerShell as separate service also I'm not consider. I'm expecting that someone can explain why my yml do not get through?

Changing apt to apk won't work neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to escape end-of-lines using the backslash character, but your command string doesn't actually have multiple lines. When you write your YAML like this:

```
some_key: some value
  that looks like
  it is multiple lines
```

The resulting value of `some_key` is `some value that looks like it has multiple lines`. It's just a string with no line breaks. So given how you've written your `docker-compose.yaml`...

```yaml
command: bash -c "apt-get update && \
                  apt-get install -y curl gnupg apt-transport-https && \
                  curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
                  echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/powershell.list && \
                  apt-get update && \
                  apt-get install -y powershell && \
                  apt-get clean && \
                  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
                  su jenkins -c 'java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war'"
```

The value of `command` is actually:

```
bash -c "apt-get update && \ apt-get install -y curl gnupg apt-transport-https && \ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc ...
```

Rather than escaping a end-of-line, your `\`  is escaping the following space character, so `bash` is looking for a command named  `apt-get` with a leading space.

If you want an actual multi-line shell script, you would write your document like this:

```yaml
command:
  - bash
  - -c
  - |
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg apt-transport-https && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/powershell.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y powershell && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    su jenkins -c 'java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war'"
```

This does two things: it uses the list format of `command` key, and it uses the literal block quote operator (`|`) to embed a multi-line string as the argument to the `-c` option.

---

Your script doesn't actually need to be multiple lines, so you could use your original document and simply remove the escaping:

```yaml
command: bash -c "apt-get update &&
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg apt-transport-https &&
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - &&
    echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/powershell.list &&
    apt-get update &&
    apt-get install -y powershell &&
    apt-get clean &&
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&
    su jenkins -c 'java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war'"
```

Comment: Man you are genius ! I was not attentive ! Thanks !